# Add visual-line-mode hook to tbemail

Tags: emacs

I am using tbemail.el with Thunderbird+External Editor Extension to compose letters in emacs. The `major-mode` for this is `tbemail` and yet I cannot add a hook to use `visual-line-mode` (automatically) for these buffers. The following lines are what I have in my .emacs file:

```
(require 'tbemail)
(add-hook 'tbemail 'visual-line-mode)
(add-hook 'tbemail-mode 'visual-line-mode)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hook is "tbemail-mode-hook" so try this instead:

```
(add-hook 'tbemail-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)
```

Comment: Ah, really that simple??? Embarrassed, after having used and customized Emacs for many years...